# jQuery doesnt work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my code:

```
    /// <reference path="../jquery-1.5.1.js" />
jQuery(function($){
    $(".deleteLink").click(function () {
        alert(1);
    });
});

$(".deleteLink").click(function () {


    alert(2);
});
```

This is my link:

```
<a class="deleteLink" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#1" href="/Admin/Delete?deleteID=1&amp;unDelete=1" id="1">Delete</a>
```

In both cases whenever i press on the link no alert pops up.

Here are my links in the html file:

update:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/AdminScript/AdminMenu.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> //External file where I execute my javascript/jquery code
```

Comment: Obvious question: is jQuery actually being loaded?

Comment: It should, did you try putting that in `$(document).ready(function{...})`? Or make sure that your link is present when script is launched?

Comment: jquery is in external javascript file

Answer (score 5):

The first part of your code uses an incorrect identifier to access jQuery. 
Try replacing `$jQuery` with either `jQuery` or `$`.

```
$(function(){
  $(".deleteLink").click(function () {
     alert(1);
  });
});
```

The second bit probably fails because you put it in the header. This code is executed immediately so if you put that in the header of the html the specified link doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
  $('.deleteLink').click(function(){
    alert('Hello world');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".deleteLink").click(function () {
        alert(1);
        return false;
    });
});
```